# RecyclerView not updating View

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view. For the first time, it loads all the data and the view is shown perfect. But when the data is added dynamically, pull to refresh, I add it to the list of data and call notifyDataSetChanged. It increases the count of the list and the list is updated with the latest data but the view is not updating with the latest data added to the list. onBindViewHolder has the updated listView size and the listView has all the valid data within it.

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: HistoryListAdapter.ViewHolder?, position: Int) {
        info("onBindViewHolder =>"+listAssets.size)
        info("onBindViewHolder itemCount =>"+itemCount)
        info("onBindViewHolder position =>"+position)
    val notesButton = holder?.notesButton
    val notesView = holder?.notesTextView

    val dateTime = listAssets[position].date
    val location = listAssets[position].location

    val sessionId = listAssets[position].id
    holder?.sessionID = sessionId
    holder?.portraitImageView?.setImageDrawable(listAssets[position].image)
    holder?.titleTextView?.text = DateTimeFormatter.getFormattedDate(context, dateTime)

    val timeString = DateTimeFormatter.getFormattedTime(context, dateTime)

    if (location.length != 0) {
        holder?.subtitleTextView?.text = "$timeString @ $location"
    } else {
        holder?.subtitleTextView?.text = "$timeString"
    }

    val data = listAssets[position].data

    for (actionData in data) {
        val inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        val parent = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history_card_action, null)

        val icon = parent?.findViewById(R.id.historyActionIcon) as ImageView
        val title = parent?.findViewById(R.id.historyActionTitle) as TextView
        val subtitle = parent?.findViewById(R.id.historyActionSubtitle) as TextView

        var iconDrawable: Drawable? = null

        when(actionData.type) {

            ActionType.HEART -> {
                iconDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.heart)
            }
            ActionType.LUNGS -> {
                iconDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.lungs)
            }
            ActionType.TEMPERATURE -> {
                iconDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.temperature)
            }
        }

        icon.setImageDrawable(iconDrawable)

        val titleString = actionData.title

        titleString?.let {
            title.text = titleString
        }

        val subtitleString = actionData.subtitle

        subtitleString?.let {
            subtitle.text = subtitleString
        }

        holder?.actionContainer?.addView(parent)
    }


    val notes = listAssets[position].notes
    notesView?.text = notes

    if (notes.length == 0) {
        notesButton?.layoutParams?.width = 0
    } else {
        notesButton?.layoutParams?.width = toggleButtonWidth
    }

    if (expandedNotes.contains(sessionId)) {
        notesView?.expandWithoutAnimation()
    } else {
        notesView?.collapseWithoutAnimation()
    }

    notesButton?.onClick {
        notesView?.toggleExpansion()
    }
}


    data class ListAssets(val id: String,
                              val date: Date,
                              val location: String,
                              val notes: String,
                              val image: Drawable,
                              val data: ArrayList<ListData>)

        data class ListData(val type: ActionType,
                            val title: String?,
                            val subtitle: String?)

override fun onViewRecycled(holder: HistoryListAdapter.ViewHolder?) {
        super.onViewRecycled(holder)

        if (holder != null) {
            holder.actionContainer.removeAllViews()

            val notesTextView = holder.notesTextView

            if (notesTextView != null) {
                if (notesTextView.expandedState) {
                    val sessionID = holder.sessionID

                    sessionID?.let {
                        val sessionSearch = expandedNotes.firstOrNull {
                            it.contentEquals(sessionID)
                        }

                        if (sessionSearch == null) {
                            expandedNotes.add(sessionID)
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    val sessionID = holder.sessionID

                    sessionID?.let {
                        val sessionSearch = expandedNotes.firstOrNull {
                            it.contentEquals(sessionID)
                        }

                        if (sessionSearch != null) {
                            expandedNotes.remove(sessionSearch)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

ActionView is Enum.

Kindly please let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: Could you try switching to "var parent = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history_card_action, holder?.actionContainer, false)" when inflating the view?